# An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig)

Tags: installation, command-line

Help Me. i am using all latest version.

During the installation of Magento 2.4 an error appears when creating an admin account:
An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig)

Comment: php bin/magento module:enable --all && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy